# Setting Up an SNS Topic to trigger a Lambda Function one message after an other

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sns

I have a service that uses a JSON file on an S3 bucket for its configuration. 
I would like to be able to modify this file, but I'm going to run into a concurrency issue as multiple administrators will be able to write in this file at the same time.
I'm going to use an SNS Topic to trigger a lambda that will write the config changes. 
For the moment, I'm going to check the queue every minute and then handle the messages, so that I am sure that I don't have multiple instances of lambda running at the same time and writing in the same file.

Is there any way to have an SNS topic to trigger a lambda function for each message, and then wait for this message to be handled and then move on to the next one?

Cheers,
Julien

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by setting the max concurrent executions of your Lambda function to 1. See the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/concurrent-executions.html) for more details about managing concurrency for Lambdas.